# Swapping fixed values

Tags: excel, data-structures, data-analysis

I try to simplify the scenario as much as possible,

Is there a way to swap unique values in a column?

Meaning to say for column A, i have A to Z which is at A1 to A26, then when lets say, i enter J at A1 (which is originally an A) the cell at A10 (J) will be automatically swapped to show an A? Or i enter B at the place of Z and Z will automatically appear at B hence the swap

The intent is to swap values around so my program can calculate accordingly when trying out different subjects

Comment: With VBA for sure. With normal Excel formulas not sure. Anyways, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the advice given in the comments to see why your question is being downvoted. However, I find the case you describe pretty interesting so I gave it a shot. Insert the following code into the worksheet module in VBA.

```
Dim oldVal As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then oldVal = Target.Value2
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A26")

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim newVal As String
        newVal = Target.Value2
        Target.Value2 = oldVal

        Dim newValRng As Range
        Set newValRng = rng.Find(newVal, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
        If Not newValRng Is Nothing Then
            newValRng.Value2 = oldVal
            Target.Value2 = newVal
        Else
            MsgBox ("Please enter a value that is already in range " & rng.Address)
        End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

To explain what's going on a little: Every time the user selects a single cell in the workbook the value of that cell is stored in `oldVal`. TO be super safe you could also perform this on `Workbook_Open` to cover the edge case of a user not changing the selection before changing the value.

Then, when a cell is changed it the new value is stored in `newVal` and the change is reverted. Next, the cell with `newVal` is identified. If no such cell exists an error message is shwon and no changes happen. If a cell is found it is assigned the value of `oldVal` and the user's original change is redone.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Schalk, im new to the forum, didnt take note of those posting requirements. Will make sure to show work ive done. Was just trying to not complicate the scenario too much by keeping it simple

Comment: Don't worry, we're all here to learn. Did my code solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Schalk, the code worked, very amazing, thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to help, please consider accepting the answer and upvoting, so others might find this better

Comment: Okay, ive upvoted and clicked the tick but the website tells me that my reputation is too low to make any difference 

Comment: Don't worry about it =)